# Oracle XML need 2 rows of data values, not 1 row of XMLTYPEs

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I'm very new to Oracle XML and am trying to retrieve 2 rows of 4 columns of vehicle data.

SQL:

```
select extract(xml, 'VEHICLES/VEHICLE/NUM_VEHICLE') as NUM_VEHICLE,
       extract(xml, 'VEHICLES/VEHICLE/NUM_YEAR') as NUM_YEAR,
       extract(xml, 'VEHICLES/VEHICLE/DES_PLATE') as DES_PLATE,
       extract(xml, 'VEHICLES/VEHICLE/CDE_STATE') as CDE_STATE
  from XML_TAB_HISTORY t
 where t.id = 7
```

XML:

```
<VEHICLES>
  <VEHICLE>
    <NUM_VEHICLE>1</NUM_VEHICLE>
    <NUM_YEAR>2011</NUM_YEAR>
    <DES_PLATE>ABC123</DES_PLATE>
    <CDE_STATE>NJ</CDE_STATE>
  </VEHICLE>
  <VEHICLE>
    <NUM_VEHICLE>2</NUM_VEHICLE>
    <NUM_YEAR>2012</NUM_YEAR>
    <DES_PLATE>XYZ987</DES_PLATE>
    <CDE_STATE>NJ</CDE_STATE>
  </VEHICLE>
</VEHICLES>
```

I'm getting 1 row of 4 XMLTYPEs:

```
<NUM_VEHICLE>1</NUM_VEHICLE>
<NUM_VEHICLE>2</NUM_VEHICLE>

<NUM_YEAR>2011</NUM_YEAR>
<NUM_YEAR>2012</NUM_YEAR>

<DES_PLATE>ABC123</DES_PLATE>
<DES_PLATE>XYZ987</DES_PLATE>

<CDE_STATE>NJ</CDE_STATE>
<CDE_STATE>NJ</CDE_STATE>
```

What I'd like to get is 2 rows of values only:

```
NUM_VEHICLE  NUM_YEAR  DES_PLATE  CDE_STATE
-----------  --------  ---------  ---------
1            2011      ABC123     NJ
2            2012      XYZ987     NJ
```

I tried using "extractvalue" in place of extract in the SQL, but received this error: **ORA-19025: EXTRACTVALUE returns value of only one node**.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or pointers in the right direction.

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `extract` and `extractvalue` are deprecated, so you should be using `xmlquery` and, in this case, `xmltable`:

```
select num_vehicle, num_year, des_plate, cde_state
from xml_tab_history t
cross apply xmltable (
  '/VEHICLES/VEHICLE'
  passing t.xml
  columns num_vehicle number path 'NUM_VEHICLE',
    num_year number path 'NUM_YEAR',
    des_plate varchar2(6) path 'DES_PLATE',
    cde_state varchar2(2) path 'CDE_STATE'
) x
where t.id = 7
```

```
NUM_VEHICLE NUM_YEAR DES_PLATE CDE_STATE
----------- -------- --------- ---------
          1     2011 ABC123    NJ       
          2     2012 XYZ987    NJ
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a9b5d9447b4def0816446c88e313afd5)

[Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/xquery-and-XML-DB.html#GUID-4805CF1C-A00D-4B88-AF2E-00A9DB6F3392) about current SQL/XML functions.

Comment: Alex, just wanted to say your example was extremely helpful. I discovered I needed to link  2 more tables for a later query and with a little study figured out how to add another "cross" apply and an "outer" apply and pass child XMLTYPEs to get everything I needed.